# On Radon-Nikodym property of a dual of a Bochner space

Tags: reference-request, measure-theory, duality

Let ${\rm S}^{n-1}$ be the unit sphere of ${\bf R}^n$ and let us consider the dual of the space $L^p\left({\bf R}^n; C^1({\rm S}^{n-1})\right)$, for some $p\in\langle1,\infty\rangle$: it is the space of all weakly-$\ast$ measurable functions $T:{\bf R}^n\to \left(C^1({\rm S}^{n-1})\right)'$ such that the integral $\int_{{\bf R}^{n}} \| T(x)\|_{\left(C^1({\rm S}^{n-1})\right)'}\; dx$ is finite. It is sometimes denoted by $L^{p'}_w\left({\bf R}^n;\left(C^1({\rm S}^{n-1})\right)'\right)$ (see the proof on the page 33 of [click here](http://www.mis.mpg.de/preprints/ln/lecturenote-0298.pdf)).

My question is: does (at least in some form) the Radon-Nikodym property ([click here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral#Radon.E2.80.93Nikodym_property)) hold for space $L^{p'}_w\left({\bf R}^n;\left(C^1({\rm S}^{n-1})\right)'\right)$?

I have seen several results that require reflexivity, but $C^1({\rm S}^{n-1})$ is not reflexive (we only have separability), so they do not apply to this case.

Comment: For the classical Radon-Nikodym property, the answer is negative. In the book Vector measures by Diestel and Uhl , at the bottom of page 98 there is Theorem 1 which gives a characterisation of spaces with RNP. If the RNP were to hold, then we would have that the dual of $L^p({\bf R}^d; C^1({\rm S}^{d-1}))$ would be precisely $L^{p'}\left({\bf R}^d; (C^1({\rm S}^{d-1}))'\right)$, which is not the case.